# UPloading files

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload

I have a question about how the upload and download system works with php and mysql.

I want to upload mp3 files so that only a specific user(logged in) can view available files sorted in some catagories and download the ones he/she wants while few of them would be available publicly and anyone can download them

I feel really stupid asking this but where is the files then saved? Inside a table? Or does the table point to a directory in my webserver?
and how to store the file path into the database. udload should take place on server side not on the webpage. My audio files are available on local disk.

I'm asking this as I really want to learn this but even the basic questions can be difficult even to formulate let alone solve... :)

I am stuck as i want to store the file path in database so it can be downloaded  by users.

Looking forward for some input

Comment: [storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = "/path_to_folder/";// target to which the file needs to be saved

$filepath = $target . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']);// path of the file in server

//upload file like this
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

// here insert $filepath in to DB

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbanme");

$query = "insert in tablename(filepath) values($filepath)";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die (mysqli_error($con));

}
```